# OP wants to upvote and accept my answer but doesn't have enough rep

Tags: support

Good morning,
The person who asked this [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/42786/how-does-cupids-arrow-effect-the-story-house-of-hades-spoilers/43192#43192) wants to upvote and accept it as the answer.
However, he says he can't do either because he doesn't have enough rep?
What are his options?
Thank you,

Answer (score 7):

Everyone who asks a question can accept an answer, regardless of reputation. Instructions are in the [help center](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Once I post this, you'll see the gray checkmark right

about

here

<---

It takes 15 reputation to upvote, see the [privileges page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up).

Comment: thanks, I'll send him a link to this.

Comment: Also, gaining 15 rep on this site is... not to sound too flippant but it's beyond trivial. Even more so now, since you get +2 for edits

Comment: @DVK It's always been +2rep for edits, at least 2 years.

Comment: @Kevin - that dates me, ain't it? :)

Comment: @dvk It looks like the rep began [Feb 2, 2011](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77505/172958), so about 2y8mo ago.

Comment: @Kevin - I joined SO 4 years ago :) And by the time I realized I can gain rep from edits on SFF, I already had too much rep to be rewardable :)

Comment: @DVK Early on you also get rep by accepting an answer, I think

Comment: @Izkata You still do. 2 rep, as long as it's not your answer and not a CW question.

Comment: @Kevin I ask questions so rarely on any site, I can never remember the specifics  =P